# Different color points in facet_wrap depending on criteria

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a dataframe with few timeseries in the same plot and I am using `ggplot`+`facet_wrap`.

I want to select specific points meeting a specific criteria (which it might be different for each column) and plot them in a different colour.

I have been fiddling with `facet_wrap`, `mutate_at`, I have been trying to add a column with the colour factor and to plot each facet once with different colour... but in the end I had no success

the basic code I am using is:

```r
df <- data.frame("date" = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), "%F %T"), tz="UTC"),
                                     length.out=20, by="min"), 
                 "a" = rnorm(20,0,3), 
                 "b" = rnorm(20,1,2), 
                 "c"= rnorm(20,1,4))

require(magrittr)
require(ggplot2)


df %>%   
    reshape2::melt(id = "date") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=date,y=value, colour=)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free") +
    ggtitle("MWE") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "red", size = 20, face = "bold")) +
    theme_bw() -> plt

print(plt)
```

The output is ok, although, what I would like is to have red dots in each negative value in facet "a", green dots in each value above 1.5 in the facet "b" and so forth.

BTW: Why I can't get the main title in the center and with a different colour?

Thanks!

[image: result of the mwe above]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "and so forth", but I hope you can fill the missing piece using a similar logic I've employed for adding a layer for `a` and `b`. I've used `dplyr` instead of `magrittr` as it is included already.

```r
# lib and your data 
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 
df <- data.frame("date" = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(),"%F %T"),tz="UTC"),length.out=20,by="min"), "a" = rnorm(20,0,3), "b" = rnorm(20,1,2), "c"= rnorm(20,1,4))
df

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# I broke your script into piece as it is easier for me to understand. 
mydf <- df %>% reshape2::melt(id = "date")

base <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line()

b_wrap <- base + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")

b_title <- b_wrap + labs(title = "MWE")

# once you've used theme_bw() you're formatting will be lost, so
# customize something that looks like theme_bw()

b_title_format <- b_title + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "red", size = 20, face = "bold"), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color="gray"), axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"))

# get the plot data from b_title_format
plot_data = b_title_format$data

# subset the required data from plot_data 
a_data <- subset(plot_data, variable == "a" & value < 0)
b_data <- subset(plot_data, variable == "b" & value > 1.5)

# add a layer plot_title_format 

b_title_format + geom_point(a_data, mapping = aes(x = date, y=value), col = "red") + geom_point(b_data, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value), col = "green")
```

## Output

[image: facet_output]